# How to intercept web requests made by an IP camera?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip-camera, traffic

My IP camera is connected via wireless to the router. The router does not support logging.

I am wondering what is the best way to intercept the traffic between the IP camera and the internet, specifically finding out what domains/URLs are requested and what data is being sent.

Is there any way to intercept that in the router?